# How to find the position of a string in another string without the find() and index() method?

Tags: python, loops, indexing

My task is to write a code that reproduces the str.find() method. I'm not allowed to use these:
str.find(), str.index(), str.split().

So far I have:

```
string = "haystack"
if " needle " in (" " + string + " "):
    print(#here I want to print the first index in which "needle" is in "haystack"
else:
    print(„-1“))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are simply looking for a way to solve the problem at all (and not in a particularly efficient way), perhaps it would help to consider this type of logic (in pseudocode):

```
for index i in str
  if searchStr is in str starting at index i
    return i
return -1
```

where:

- `str` is input string to search through ('haystack')
- `searchStr` is input string to search for ('needle')